# PowerQuery Splitting cell into separate rows

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a column with a list of persons, but in a string format. I need to convert it into a list or table, so I can duplicate the line expanding this column.

[image]

Somebody knows if is it possible?

I expect to have this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, right click the column ... split column .. by delimiter ... use custom with ; space ,  each occurrence, and in advanced options choose rows

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"AT", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("; ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "AT")
in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]